# Reference an external JavaScript file using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using Vue.js 2.0 and I need to reference an external JavaScript file and I have this in my index.html file

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js'></script>
```

The index.html has a

```
   <div id="app"></div>
```

And my router loads my Home.vue page

the home page injects another page called tabs.vue

```
     import tabComponent from '@/components/tab.vue'
```

Referencing the external JavaScript file from the tab.vue page works fine.  My problem is that when I inject a page into the tab.vue page as a component that page has no idea of the external JavaScript file.

```
        import newProfile from '../components/profile.vue'
```

How can I reference the External JavaScript file another layer deep?  I was under the impression that putting the script tag into the index.html head section that it would be global.  What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: You can always use `@/` just try it out. `resolve()` makes that `src/` for you. You don't have to import things relative to each other. Why do you mention the external JavaScript file? Is that a component? Better use a package to add that, except if that is just webfonts and icons.

Comment: The external JavaScript file is a commercial company that I have no control over.  They follow Researchers Publications    https://www.altmetric.com/

Comment: It's the altmetric file that I need to use

Comment: I tried to reproduce in a [mcve] but was unable to. Things worked as expected. This is probably because your question is missing important context. When you say "when I inject a page into the tab.vue page as a component that page has no idea of the external JavaScript file", how do you do this? Could you update your question to include this code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it.  I still have the reference on the index.html page, not sure if I need it but I also added the reference on the profile.vue component page right above the script tag

```
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://d1bxh8uas1mnw7.cloudfront.net/assets/embed.js'></script>
```

Then I can reference the properties without any trouble.  There maybe a cleaner way to do this so please post your suggestions